# Using a unique_ptr to an array of floats

Tags: c++, arrays

I wrote a File IO library.  One function, `File::read` looks like this:

```
template <typename T>
void File::read(T * t, unsigned long count) const
```

It reads `count` T into `*t`.

Now, skipping to the client.  I allocate a memory buffer which I want to read into.  I wrote this and it works great:

```
float * buffer = new float [16];
file->read(buffer, 16);
```

However, this not exception safe.  So I decided to wrap the buffer in a `std::unique_ptr`.  Somewhere in here I am making a mistake.

```
std::unique_ptr<float[]> buffer (new float[16]);
file->read(*buffer , 16);
```

This produces the following error on file->read:

> no match for 'operator*' (operand type is 'std::unique_ptr')

I thought that by dereferencing the `unique_ptr` I'd get a pointer to the first element of the `float[]` array.  Where is my mistake and what is the fix?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of problems: The first is that you make a `std::unique_ptr` of `float[]` (i.e. you have a pointer to arrays of `float`).

The other problem is that smart pointers acts just as normal pointers. When you dereference a normal pointer with the `*` operator, you no longer have a pointer but a value (the value of what the pointer points to).

---

Also, I would suggest you to use either [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) (if you know the size at compile-time) or [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of smart pointers. In modern C++ there is almost no need for pointers at all.

You could use it like

```
std::array<float, 16> buffer;
file->read(buffer.data(), buffer.size());
```

If you don't have `std::array` you can use `std::vector` instead:

```
std::vector<float> buffer(16);  // Create a vector of 16 floats,
                                // default initialized (i.e. 0.0)

// &buffer[0] is a pointer to the first element in the vector
// all vectors are guaranteed to be contiguous like normal arrays
file->read(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
```

Comment: I wouldn't know how to read into the vector from a binary file (byte stream), I'm afraid.  The `File::read` call just reads `count * sizeof(T)` bytes directly into the memory pointed to by `T * t`.  I I am looking for a fix to my method.

Comment: Oh, `std::array::data` returns a pointer to a contiguous and changable block of memory, so I can read into that!  That should work.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you post the correct way to do it in my (deprecated) style?  It might be useful to know for learning purposes.

Comment: @jakeliquorblues How about now?